# not defining array's length in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I'm using fetch to get the product as an object and while setting it to my state I'm adding new key `comments: []` to the object. If I `console.log(product.comments)` it's returning empty array which's correct but when I `console.log(product.comments.length)` it says `can't access property "length", product.comments is undefined`

```
useEffect(() => {
    
    setLoading(true)
    fetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${id}`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            setProduct({ ...data, comments: [] })
            setLoading(false)
        })
        .catch((err) => console.error(err))
}, [id])
```

what did I do wrong, how to get the length of `comments` so that I can map it?
this is what I wanna do

```
`{product.comments.length ? (
  comments.map((comment) => {
   return (
    <li>
     <div className="testimonial">
      <p className="quote">{comment.comment}</p>
     </div>
    </li>
   )
 })
 ) : (
    <h2>Be first to comment</h2>
 )}`
```

I also tried logging `product.comments.length` to console but got the same error

Comment: Nowhere in the code shown are you logging that data to the console.  Are you referring to some other code?  Can you provide a [mcve] of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are trying to access `comments` even before it's set on the product you should just check if `product` is not empty or set before you can access any property on it.

```js
if(product) {
    return {product.comments.length ? (comments.map((comment) => {
       return (<li>
            <div className="testimonial">
                <p className="quote">{comment.comment}</p>
            </div>
        </li>);
    })) : (
      <h2>Be first to comment</h2>
   )};
} else {
    return <p>Product loading</p>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to render cycles. Either early return from your component e.g.

```
// data, isLoading, error = fetchData()

if (isLoading) { return <div>Loading …</div>
if (error) { return <div>Error</div> }

return ( <div>Your component body</div>)
```

Or you could check if the property exists before accessing the `length` property using the optional [chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

```
{product?.comments.length ? (product.comments.map( … )) : (<h2>Be first to comment</h2>)}
```